# Can i periodically write all POST requests (within that time frame) in file in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have jmeter loading my web service with load at around 2000 events per sec.
I want to log all my requests. Is there any way where i can write all my out going requests periodically? Basically i want to write outgoing requests in csv format every 15 mins?
Is it possible?

I am new to jmeter so a detailed answer will help a lot

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure JMeter to store request details by adding the next few lines to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
```

So if you run JMeter on [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) .jtl result file will contain all request details.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details on various JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them

Just for reference here are other properties which can be used to define which values can be stored in results file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"?>
jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but quite complex, and maybe won't improve the throughput as you'd hope.

You can add a beanshell listener to your test plan.

Within the beanshell code you can measure time elapsed, and record the current sample to memory.

When enough time has elapsed you can write the memory samples to file and flush memory.

It appears you are trying to allow for the performance of the client logging not affecting the server under test.  An alternative approach to logging at intervals (which is going to make your test results look like a sawtooth), you could try using distributed jmeter testing, and have enough clients running to test your server thoroughly, rather than trying to make your client perform better.

Then you can just use the 'Save responses to a file' listener.

If your tests are limited by the client capability, you simply need more client power to test the server, or look at other ways to improve client/test plan performance.

Comment: Save responses to a file will not save request, right? I need to save requests and i can live with reduced throughput.
So anyone can help me on that front?